# Visualforce page not working in Chrome Browser

Tags: visualforce, chrome

I have one Inline visualforce page which is visible in Firefox browser but not visible in Chrome browser for Custom profile.

However, this page is working fine for System Administrator in Chrome browser.

I have provided all the required  permissions (Visualforce page and Apex class) to the Custom profile.

Thanks,
Suraj

Comment: What do you mean by "not visible"? What does chrome development console says?

Comment: Hi please see [ask] - you would help by posting the VF code or the skeleton of it here to see if there is anything in it which is likely to cause it to fail to load in chrome.